# Conflict error when using \pstMarkAngle with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, errors, pstricks, ghostscript

I’m trying to produce a pspicture with marked angles, so I’m using the pstricks extention pst-eucl. Here is a minimal example: (I’m using MikTeX 9.25 together with TeXmaker on Windows 7)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{xunicode}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-tools,pst-plot,pst-eucl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
       \resizebox{0.8\linewidth}{!}{
            \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(6,6)
                \psset{nodesep=-1cm}
                \psset{PointName=none, PointSymbol=none}
                \pstGeonode[PosAngle=90](0,1){A}(5,2){B}(0,4){C}(5,3){D}(2,5){E}(4,0){F}
                \pstLineAB{A}{B}
                \pstLineAB{C}{D}
                \pstLineAB{E}{F}
                \pstInterLL{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}
                \pstInterLL{A}{B}{E}{F}{H}
                \uput[135](C){\Large $(d_1)$} \uput[135](A){\Large $(d_2)$} \uput[45](E){\Large $(d_3)$}
                \pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=gray,  MarkAngleRadius=.5]{H}{G}{D}{}
                \pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=gray, MarkAngleRadius=.7]{G}{H}{A}{}
            \end{pspicture}                 
       }
  \end{center}
```

\end{document}

It seems that there is some kind of conflict between pstricks and XeLaTeX. 
When using `\pstMarkAngle` this is the message of error I get:

> MikTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25 : Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

It slows down the compilation but doesn’t break it though. At the end, the compiler announces that there were no errors. This is unconvenient because when loading multiple pspictures containing `\pstMarkAngle` the compilation takes much more longer.

The problem does not seem to take place when using `LaTeX` instead of `XeLaTeX`. But changing to `LaTeX` for me is not the desired solution.

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong? I searched for the solution with no success, and any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

no problem with an up-to-date TeXLive 2019:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{pst-tools,pst-plot,pst-eucl}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{0.8\linewidth}{!}{%
    \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(6,6)
        \psset{nodesep=-1cm}
        \psset{PointName=none, PointSymbol=none}
        \pstGeonode[PosAngle=90](0,1){A}(5,2){B}(0,4){C}(5,3){D}(2,5){E}(4,0){F}
        \pstInterLL{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}
        \pstInterLL{A}{B}{E}{F}{H}
        \uput[135](C){\Large $(d_1)$} \uput[135](A){\Large $(d_2)$} \uput[45](E){\Large $(d_3)$}
        \pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=gray,  MarkAngleRadius=.5]{H}{G}{D}{}
        \pstMarkAngle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=gray, MarkAngleRadius=.7]{G}{H}{A}{}
        \pstLineAB{A}{B}
        \pstLineAB{C}{D}
        \pstLineAB{E}{F}
    \end{pspicture}%
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For MikTeX try the following under Windows in a cmd command window:

```
xelatex --no-pdf <file>
xdvipdfmx -dNoSafer -vv <file>.xdv
```

it should create a document and in the terminal output you'll see what's the problem.

Comment: Good to know. Although changing from MikTeX to TeXlive may generate other complications for me. Is it an inner problem in MikTeX or si there a fix for this situation somewhere?

Comment: see at the end of my answer.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, didn’t see the end of the message. I tried the compiling instructions you suggested, and the log file indicates some problems relating to the language, nothing about pstMarkAngle, although nothing in the code indicates that I am using other language than English, there is no accents in the text. Here is some of the messages of the log file:
- Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 35 replaced by U+FFFD.
- Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)  this).
- LaTeX Font Info:Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 21.

Comment: Out-of-topic: I found a weird thing in which `pst-news16` shows `2017`.